# Comprobar caracter a caracter un string pasada por argumento

Tags: array, c, codeblocks, archivo

intento resumirlo intento pasar como tercer argumento una palabra y tengo que validar que no sea un número o que contenga alguno para luego buscar esa palabra y imprimir el texto que acompaña esa palabra que se encuentra dentro del fichero. Tengo una función que me valida que me mira/comprueba que no haya un numero pero no me lo hace y se lo salta:

```
#define MAXCADENA 200
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <locale.h>
bool esLetra(char cadenaBuscar[MAXCADENA]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    FILE *f;
    char cadenaMostrar[MAXCADENA];
    char cadenaBuscar[MAXCADENA];

    if(argc!=3) printf("ERROR DE PARAMETROS");
    else{
        strcpy(cadenaBuscar,argv[2]);
        if(!esLetra(cadenaBuscar)) printf("Incorrecto");
        else{
            printf("\nNombre del fichero %s\n\n",argv[1]);
            f=fopen(argv[1],"rt");
            if(f==NULL) printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero");
            else{
                fgets(cadenaMostrar,MAXCADENA,f);
                while(feof(f)==0){
                    printf("%s",cadenaMostrar);
                    fgets(cadenaMostrar,MAXCADENA,f);
                }
                printf("%d",cadenaBuscar);
                fclose(f);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool esLetra(char cadenaBuscar[MAXCADENA]){
    char lletres[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÈÉÍÏÒÓÚÜÑÇ";
    cadenaBuscar=toupper(cadenaBuscar);
    int i =0;
    bool encontrada = false;
    while(lletres[i]!='\0' && !encontrada){
        if(lletres[i]==cadenaBuscar){
            encontrada = true;
        }else{
            i++;
        }
    }
    return encontrada;
}
```

Comment: Esta comparación: `if(lletres[i]==cadenaBuscar)` no cuadra. La variable `lletres[i]` hace referencia a 1 carácter, mientras que la variable `cadenaBuscar` es un puntero a un *array* de caracteres. ¿Acaso el compilador no te da mensajes de advertencias? Por ejemplo: `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`. Por otro lado tienes esta asignación alegremente: `cadenaBuscar=toupper(cadenaBuscar);`. El método implícito `toupper()` espera un carácter, y le estas pasando un puntero. Analiza bien las variables que estás usando porque el problema está en que no lo sabes. Saludos

Comment: Si, hace poco que empece con strings y ficheros en C por lo que muchas cosas me falta por mejorar. Y no, el compilador directamente lo compila sin problemas no me da ningún tipo de error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para examinar una cadena, la recorremos comprobando caracter a caracter, hasta detectar una de dos situaciones:

- Llegamos al fin de la cadena (caracter == 0), o
- Encontramos un caracter que no es alfabético.

Entonces, si al salir de ciclo el último caracter examinado es 0, quiere decir que la cadena completa está compuesta de caracteres alfabéticos (o está vacia). En caso contrario, no es una cadena alfabética.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool esLetra(char cadenaBuscar[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (cadenaBuscar[i] && isalpha(cadenaBuscar[i])) {
        i++;
    }
    return !cadenaBuscar[i];
}
```

Nota: supongo que está permitido usar las funciones de clasificación, dado que usas `toupper`. En caso contrario, puedes usar está implementación:

```
bool is_alpha(char x) {
    static char alfabeto[] = "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ";
    
    if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z') return true;
    if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') return true;
    
    int i = 0;
    while (alfabeto[i] && alfabeto[i] != x) {
        i++;
    }
    return alfabeto[i] == x;
}
```

La función primero clasifica por rango, dado que de la 'a' a la 'z' son contiguos. Lo mismo con las mayúsculas.

Si no es una letra fácil, luego se busca en `alfabeto`. Puedes editar está variable para agregar más caracteres alfabéticos, si es necesario. Por ejemplo, ¿el espacio se considera alfabético? Si es asi, agregalo a `alfabeto`.

**Comprobación**

```
void clasifica(char cadena[]) {
    if (esLetra(cadena)) {
        printf("%s es letra\n", cadena);
    } else {
        printf("%s no es letra\n", cadena);
    }    
}

int main(){
    char cadena1[] = "abcABCefg";
    char cadena2[] = "abc123";
    char cadena3[] = "JoséNuñez";
    
    clasifica(cadena1);
    clasifica(cadena2);
    clasifica(cadena3);
}
```

produce:

```
abcABCefg es letra
abc123 no es letra
JoséNuñez es letra
```

Comment: Una duda y perdona que lo pregunte, pero en la primera función cuando devuelves un !cadenaBuscar[i] realmente que estas devolviendo, es la primera vez que lo veo y me resulta un poco confuso. Por el resto me ha quedado muy claro, gracias!

Comment: @Wail. En C/C++, el valor cero es falso y todo lo demás es verdadero. Entonces, la expresion `!cadenaBuscar[i]` es una forma abreviada de `cadenaBuscar[i] != 0`, que es igual a preguntar `¿llegamos al final de la cadena?`, lo que implica que todo los caracteres pasaron la prueba.